# vuejs, bootstrap table component and fields label

Tags: vue.js

i'm using the table component of [vue-bootstrap](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org). i've defined fields as [array of objects](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#fields-as-an-array-of-objects)
and i need to have multilang label. so i've tried in data():

```
lang: "",
translations: {
    eng: { field1: "LABEL1" },
    ger: { field1: ""},
    fra: { field1: ""}
}

fields: [
        { key: "field1", label: this.translations[this.lang].field1 },
]
```

`lang` is being setted in created() using a cookie reader.

this is not working, what am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

ok, i've found the solution: the **field{}** object in **computed()**